# Find and return object in array with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to return an object from an array.

The object is founded with this code 
`_.has(myTableName.joinsData['PAIS DISTRITO'], '49')`

where my first parameter is

```
[{"99":"Estrangeiro"},{"01":"AVEIRO"},{"02":"BEJA"},{"03":"BRAGA"}, 
 {"04":"BRAGAN‌​CA"},{"05":"CASTELO BRANCO"},{"06":"COIMBRA"},
 {"07":"EVORA"},{"08":"FARO"},{"09":"GUARDA"},{"10":"LE‌​IRIA"}, 
 {"11":"LISBOA"},{"12":"PORTALEGRE"},{"13":"PORTO"},
 {"14":"SANTAREM"},{"15"‌​:"SETUBAL"},{"16":"VIANA DO CASTELO"},
 {"17":"VILA REAL"},{"18":"VISEU"},{"31":"ILHA DA MADEIRA"},
 {"32":"ILHA DE PORTO SANTO"},{"41":"ILHA DE SANTA MARIA"},
 {"42":"ILHA DE S. MIGUEL"},{"43":"ILHA TERCEIRA"},{"44":"ILHA DA GRACIOSA"},
 {"45":"ILHA DE SAO JORGE"},{"46":"ILHA DO PICO"},{"47":"ILHA DO FAIAL"},
 {"48":"ILHA DAS FLORES"}]
```

But how can i return it.

Comment: Can you show what `myTableName.joinsData['PAIS DISTRITO']` would look like? A sample?

Comment: [{"99":"Estrangeiro"},{"01":"AVEIRO"},{"02":"BEJA"},{"03":"BRAGA"},{"04":"BRAGANCA"},{"05":"CASTELO BRANCO"},{"06":"COIMBRA"},{"07":"EVORA"},{"08":"FARO"},{"09":"GUARDA"},{"10":"LEIRIA"},{"11":"LISBOA"},{"12":"PORTALEGRE"},{"13":"PORTO"},{"14":"SANTAREM"},{"15":"SETUBAL"},{"16":"VIANA DO CASTELO"},{"17":"VILA REAL"},{"18":"VISEU"},{"31":"ILHA DA MADEIRA"},{"32":"ILHA DE PORTO SANTO"},{"41":"ILHA DE SANTA MARIA"},{"42":"ILHA DE S. MIGUEL"},{"43":"ILHA TERCEIRA"},{"44":"ILHA DA GRACIOSA"},{"45":"ILHA DE SAO JORGE"},{"46":"ILHA DO PICO"},{"47":"ILHA DO FAIAL"},{"48":"ILHA DAS FLORES"}]

Comment: huh? i don't see "49" or 'PAIS DISTRITO' in the data...

Comment: deleted because too long

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs#find):

```
_.find(myTableName.joinsData['PAIS DISTRITO'], '02');

// => {"02":"BEJA"}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/np4Lbz9p/1)**</kbd>

Comment: sorry but it returns undefined!             "render": function (val, type, row) {
if(val != null){
    var result = _.find(myTableName.joinsData['PAIS DISTRITO'], val);

    alert(JSON.stringify(result));

Comment: What is `val`? In your example above you used a key as predicate

Comment: val is ok... if i use data from the fiddle , is ok , but if i use myTableName.joinsData['PAIS DISTRITO'] it returns undefined. data is a copy(myTableName.joinsData['PAIS DISTRITO']) on console. strange

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find` to iterate over the collection and return the one you're looking for.

```
var user = myTableName.joinsData.find(function(u) {
  return _.has(u, '49');
});
```

This can be cleaned up if you're using ES6 with this.

```
const user = myTableName.joinsData.find(u => _.has(u, '49'));
```